# Lowercase \mathcal

Tags: fonts, math-mode

The standard font used for `\mathcal` does not include any lowercase characters. The *Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List* suggests redefining `\mathcal` to use Zapf Chancery. However I do not particularly like that font. For example the uppercase "I" is very hard do distinguish from the non-mathcal "I". Are there any good alternatives?

Comment: Why do you want lowercase calligraphic letters in mathematics?

Comment: @Jonathan: see my answer to your "solution" below.

Comment: I'm looking for lower case calligraphy because it's used to denote lines in Birkhoff, George David (1932) \href{http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968336}{ ``A Set of Postulates for Plane Geometry (Based on Scale and Protractors),''} {\it Annals of Mathematics}, Second Series, (Apr., 1932), pp. 329-345.

Comment: @EricRasmusen [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I converted the non-answer to a comment to the question, because the area below is for actual answers.

Comment: @user10834 : The article of Birkhoff your referring to uses lower case italics to denote lines, not lowercase calligraphy.

Comment: In high school geometry, Lines are denoted with lower case script letters.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that Will Robertson hasn't dropped by and mentioned [the STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/) as these have the lowercase calligraphic (and lowercase blackboard bold) glyphs.

There doesn't yet seem to be a simple LaTeX package available mapping all the glyphs to particular commands, though.  The [stix package on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/stix/) at present seems to be just a copy of the fonts themselves (reorganised into correct texmf tree layout) but no style files as yet.  I recall reading on the STIX website that LaTeX-related stuff was intended, but given how long it took the fonts to be released, I'm not holding my breath!

---

As of 2018, this is now quite easy using luatex or xetex:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479/86}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

% Any of the following work, and probably many more
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
%\setmathfont{STIX}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
\mathcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
\mathbb{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

As pointed out in the comments, you need to use `\mathscr` (or `\let\mathcal=\mathscr`).

[image: Various maths fonts]

Comment: No, I deleted my incorrect answer to look at mathrsfs. They don't have lowercase when I thought they did. 8-bit LaTeX for the STIX fonts is indeed intended for their 1.2 release (1.1 is OpenType math, which will then supersede — mostly — the XITS Math font). And you can use the XITS Math font with unicode-math right now, but that requires a relatively radical change to how you might compile your document. So no good answer from me right now `:)`

Comment: I accepted this solution because that is what I will try for the notes I'm currently typing. (Note that `\mathscr` needs to be used instead of `\mathcal` to produce lowercase letters.)

Comment: From the STIX website: “Development is currently underway for the next release of the STIX fonts which will include support for LaTeX. We expect the release date to be no later than July 2012.”

Comment: @Andrew: I just realized that `unicode-math` is not mentioned in the answer, but only a comment. Do you want to edit it in, or should I do it (or add a separate answer)?

Comment: @Caramdir: if you ended up using these, would you be able to give a MWE for those of us who want to do the same thing but aren’t yet fluent in font-wrangling?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: `\usepackage{unicode-math}\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}` and compile with `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of use of this package and the output?

Comment: @einpoklum Given the age of this answer, and the advances in TeX fonts (for example, the TeX Gyre foundry), I suspect that an example would be quite different to how it was back then.

Comment: @einpoklum Nevertheless, I've added code that works as of now.

Comment: Note: LaTeX or pdflatex  does not work with these; you need XeTeX or LuaTeX:    
Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or(fontspec) LuaTeX. \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
Package unicode-math Error: Cannot be run with pdftex!(unicode-math) Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead.

Comment: So, are the Tex Gyre Pagella fonts available when using pdflatex?

Comment: `\msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}`

Answer (score 34):

A lowercase L can be done with `\ell`. But this seems to be the only lowercase letter that is included without loading any packages.

Comment: The 'calligraphic' lowercase L is an ordinary lowercase L written in a way that reduces confusion with the number 1.  Typographically it is calligraphic but mathematically it is not.

Comment: @Jonathan Fine This solves the mystery of this sole lowercase letter. Thanks.

Comment: I found this question specifically because I didn't like the default 'l', so it was great to see this answer.

Answer (score 17):

The font package `boondoxo` has both lowercase and uppercase calligraphic math symbols, as well as their **bold versions**. You may load it by `\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}`, and see whether you like it.

Comment: It would be nice to have just the lowercase set by this font, and the upper case be the standard cal letters

Comment: @relG This strange business is possible in xelatex with some tricks, might be as well in latex. However, the results will not be desirable. You really need to use the same typeface for both upper and lower case letters of the same family.

Answer (score 9):

`symbols` suggests using the `calligra` package as an alternative to Zapf Chancery. Put

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalligra}{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}
```

in the document’s preamble to use `\mathcalligra` for calligraphic symbols in the Calligra font.

/EDIT: To be honest, I’m not thrilled by the result, and I expect you won’t be either. Still, I’ll leave this here. Perhaps someone can profit from it.

Comment: When scaled correctly it is not bad, but quite a bit more "curly" than the default `\mathcal`.

Comment: I put \usepackage{calligra}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalligra}{T1}{calligra}{m}{n} in my preamble. then wrote $\mathcalligra{r} $. Upon compilation, I received, "! Font T1/calligra/m/n/10=callig15 at 14.40002pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found."

Comment: @MichaelLevy [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) has a useful comment on this approach below the Table _Math Alphabets_ (Table 316 at the time of writing).

Answer (score 8):

**Two solutions that work in standard LaTeX**, unlike above.

Solution 1: **dutchcal** = very calligraphic letters. Add this line to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{dutchcal} % \mathcal: also small letters. \mathbcal = bold ones.
```

Very calligraphic (just c,o not clearly non-normal, but the meaning of FIJQTZnrswz may be unclear to reader, as they are so non-normal, unless guessable from the context). Usage:

```
$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\\ 
\mathcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\\\ 
\mathbcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\\ 
\mathbcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
```

[image: Screenshot of output for the above code.]

Solution 2: **pzccal** = only somewhat calligraphic. I,O & some lowercase letters not clearly nonnormal unless next to their normal peers:

```
\usepackage{pzccal} % \mathpzc (alternate mathcal): also lowercase.
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{<-> s * [1.10] pzcmi7t}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
```

Usage:

```
$\mathpzc{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\ \mathpzc{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
```

[image: Screenshot of output for the above code.]

I'd go with solution 1 if the clarity seems sufficient from the context, else solution 2.

Found here: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29074

Comment: It would be really helpful to show an image of the output.

Comment: I agree. I can easily produce the images. How to easily attach them here?

Comment: This might help: [How do I get latex output to show up on tex.SE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4564) (read the comments)

Answer (score -11):

Think about meaning. Mathematical symbols are symbols used by mathematicians to carry a particular meaning (which may depend on the subject area).  Unicode takes that point of view (more-or-less) by giving each distinct mathematical symbol its own code point.

Typographically, a calligraphic **F** is an 'F' in a particular font, but mathematically it  is mathematical symbol with its own meaning.  Ordinarily Unicode does not care about the font, but for math symbols it does.

In my experience, mathematicians don't use lower-case calligraphic symbols, and as far as I know there are no Unicode code points for them.  Put another way, Knuth did not create lower-case mathematical calligraphic letters because mathematicians don't use them.

As a mathematician, I don't see a sufficiently good reason to start using them.

Comment: Algebraic geometers are usually using curly letters to denote sheaves. And there is a definition of Hom(F,G) of sheaves of homomorphisms between sheaves. So "Hom" should be curly to distinguish it from the ordinary Hom-set in the category of sheaves. Similarly e.g. for curly "Ext".

Comment: Also I have seen people using curly lower case letters to denote ideals (handwritten; in print fraktur is common but few people actually write fraktur).

Comment: @Caramdir: Harthorne's Algebraic Geometry (p 67) uses "Hom" with a calligraphic "H" and italic "om" for this concept.  The recent Bull. AMS. survey on Perverse Sheaves (de Cataldo and Migliorini) uses uppercase math italic letters for sheaves.

Comment: @Caramdir: Handwritten calligraphic 'g' indeed corresponds to typeset fraktur 'g'.  This, I think, supports my opinion.

Comment: @Jonathan: I know what Hartshorne (and other people) use. But this is a chicken-and-egg problem: As long as there are no lowercase calligraphic letters available nobody will use them. (And in my opinion calligraphic "H" with italic "om" looks terrible.)

Comment: @Caramdir: My opinion is that lowercase calligraphic letters won't be helpful to mathematicians. Your opinion is otherwise.  I agree with you about mixed font "Hom" being ugly.

Comment: Well, I’ll add another voice in support of Caramdir here.  I'm in a similar situation, where I have a class of objects (higher categories) that I’m generally using calligraphic letters for, and I have a functor into these called “Cl”, so I’d like a mathcal “l” for this.  (I’m currently using `\ell`, but it doesn’t quite typographically match the uppercase mathcal letters.)

Comment: @JonathanFine, I find your opinion that lowercase calligraphic letters won't be helpful quite extraordinary!

Comment: In computer science it's common to use \ell to range over labels in a labelled transition system. If you want to divide labels into syntactic classes, it's natural to want caligraphic letters other than \ell.

Comment: Or even the more basic, I have two different classes of functions, used regular f for the more common, now I need a different f....

Comment: In number theory, people often use lowercase calligraphic m to denote the so called minor arcs.