# How to use \mathcal with subscript? Undefined control sequence..

Tags: math-mode, mathcal

I am trying to have a cursively written l (L) with a subscript A.  I tried this:

If A has a straight line $\matchcal{l\subscript{A}}$

But I'm getting undefined control sequence.  Why is this?

Comment: See also [“Lowercase \mathcal”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479/lowercase-mathcal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realize you're using `\matchcal` instead of `\mathcal`? If your code snippet is wrong, please provide the correct piece of code, otherwise we just have to guess.

But I suppose you're looking for `\mathcal{l}_A` or `\ell_A`.

Undefined control sequences occur when LaTeX encounters something it doesn't know, such as a typo.

Comment: I'm sorry, in my rush to post this I described the issue wrong.  I get an arrow instead of a cursive l

Comment: But the \ell was the better answer, I was looking for.  Thanks

Comment: @whatnow: I disagree that `\ell` is good. It seems that some areas of math actually use it, but unless it is common for your particular use case, you should use `l` as normal. `\ell` is a way of writing on the blackboard to differentiate an l from a 1 or an I. In most fonts, this is not an issue in printed text.

Comment: Literally had this same typo (`matchcal`) and this answer helped me find it

Answer (score 1):

Since only the letter is in mathcal mode, you want `\mathcal{l}_{A}`

If you wanted an ell with a mathcal A subscript, it would be `\ell_{\mathcal{A}}` for a "cursive" ell, or `l_{\mathcal{A}}` for a regular math-italic ell with a caligraphic subscript.

For both, you would want to specify the caligraphic font separately in the "body" and "subscript". Thus, for example, `\mathcal{A}_{\mathcal{B}}`.

Comment: There is no need to specify 'to specify the caligraphic font separately in the "body" and "subscript"'. `\mathcal{A_B}` has the same effect as `\mathcal{A}_{\mathcal{B}}`