# Curly lower case 'k'

Tags: fonts, symbols

I want a symbol that it is to `$k$` as `$\ell$` is to `$l$`.

I looked at Scott Pakin's comprehensive Symbol's list and used detexify but I have not found it.

EDIT: I found a solution but it is a commercial font: http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html#Features_of_MTPro2 the cript fonts look really nice :(

Comment: If all else fails in terms of symbols, you could resort to picking a font the would provide something similar to `\ell` and `\kay` (say). Consider browsing the [LaTeX Calligraphic Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html).

Comment: See this question on [lowercase mathcal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479/lowercase-mathcal)

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in your edit, the full version of [MTPro2 from PCTeX](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) is non-free and chargeable but includes a wide range of fonts including a script font for use in mathmode that is easy to call:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mtpscr]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{kl}$
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Having exactly the same problem (in particular I was looking for a `k` which cannot be confused with a `\kappa`), I stumbled upon two interesting options, both of which are shown below. While Zapf Chancery (`pzc`) offers a nice mathcal-like font, I prefer the actual typeset of the k of the Antykwa Toruńska (`antt`)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathantt}{OT1}{antt}{li}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

$\mathantt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\mathpzc{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

\end{document}
```

[image: font examples]