# special symbol for matrix index l

Tags: matrices, subscripts

In the following image there are two different styles used for matrix index `l`. The first one is the default one. How can one get the second one?

[image]

The code is for the first equation is

```
$\sum_{kl}V_{ki}V_{lj}A_{kl}$
```

Comment: The symbol is called `\ell`, but I would recommend not using it, at least in that context where a normal "l" is not subject to confusion. On older typescripts it was difficult to distinguish between "l" and "1", so many took the habit of using a different letterform for "l".

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479/lowercase-mathcal

Comment: I'm not sure which difference you mean. You obtain the 2nd one by 1) using `\ell` as egreg suggests and 2) removing all `\rm{...}` from your code and removing `\,` from the end: `$\sum_{k\ell}V_{ki}V_{\ell j}A_{k\ell}.$`

Comment: @egreg I prefer `$\ell$` over `$l$`, I really want to avoid the confusion, especially when half of the digits in the manuscript are `1`.

Comment: @tohecz "l" is slanted enough not to be confused with "1"; but it's question of personal tastes, mainly. Talking about high quality printing, `\ell` should not be necessary at all.

Comment: `\ell` is the difference I was searching for, thanks egreg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Turning comment into answer)

The symbol is called `\ell`, but I would recommend not using it, at least in that context where a normal *l* (italic ell) is not subject to confusion. On older typescripts it was difficult to distinguish between *l* (italic ell) and 1 (one), so many took the habit of using a different letterform for *l* (italic ell).

```
$\sum_{k\ell}V_{ki}V_{\ell j}A_{k\ell}$
```

Comment: In my opinion `\ell` makes matrix equations easier to read.