# How to get the lowercase calligraphic symbols?

Tags: calligraphy

I know that we can type calligraphy words like `$\mathcal{L}$`. However, the function works only for capital characters, not for the lowercase characters. Could anyone knows how to set? Also, the bold face of the lowercase callipraphic letters is also needed.

P.S. The reason that I want to use the calligraphic lowercase letters is because the one of my textbook has used it so that I have to follow it for my work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: see [Lowercase \mathcal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479/579)

Comment: Is the euler math font of interest?  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$
\end{document}`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Three fonts have lowercase calligraphic letters and a bold version, and a LaTeX package to use them:

- `bickham` adapted for LaTeX from Adobe's `Bickham Script Pro` opentype font,
- `boondox` (with a variant `boondox-o`) (adapted from the `BOONDOXCalligraphic` STIX font),
- `dutchcal` adapted from `ESSTIX` math calligraphic font.

In addition the `mathabx` package has a `mathc` calligraphic font (in version `normal` only), but I couldn't make it work.

Here a demo:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

        %\usepackage{bickham}
        \usepackage{boondox-cal}
        %\usepackage{boondox-calo}
       % \usepackage{dutchcal}

        \pagestyle{empty}

        \begin{document}%
        \textbf{%
        % Bickham
        Boondox :
        % Boondox-o
        % Dutchcal
        }%

        \[ \begin{array}[t]{c@{\quad}c}
            \verb+ \mathcal + & \verb+ \mathbcal + \\[6pt]
            \mathcal{Em} & \mathbcal{Ln}
            \end{array} \]%

        \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Bernard I like BOONDOX-cal for lower case mathcal, but prefer the original mathcal for upper case.   I tried this as a way to ``save'' the original mathcal before calling BOONDOX:   \def\mathcalORIG#1{\mathcal{#1}}\usepackage{BOONDOX-cal}   but it didn't work.  \mathcalORIG{F}  returned BOODNOX's  F and not the default version.    Is there a way to accomplish what I want, i.e., lower case BOONDOX mathcal and upper case default mathcal.    Thanks!

Comment: Only dutchcal seems to be available on my linux box with debian packages texlive-full and texlive-math-extra installed. It makes sense that I don't have bickham, since presumably that's proprietary to Adobe.

Comment: `boondox` is also in TeX Live. Perhaps you should update. As to `bickham` I had to download the font itself for free, and install it in my `texmf-local`. There's an opentype version. The necessary files for use in LaTeX  are not part of TeX Live, but you can download them from CTAN ready-to-install in your `texmf-local` root

Comment: If `boondox-cal[o]` doesn't work try `BOONDOX-cal[o]`

Answer (score 31):

If it is only about the calligraphic `l` (which you mentioned in the question), then you can use `\ell`. This is often used to avoid confusion between the letter `l` and the number `1`. Remember that you have to use `\boldsymbol{}` to print (well..) bold symbols instead of `\mathbf{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $1 \mathbf{1}  \quad  l \mathbf{l}  \quad  \ell \boldsymbol{\ell}$
\end{document}
```

[image: ell]

If it is more general and not only about `l`, then see the question linked by @barbara beeton

Comment: is there a similar work around for the letter 'r'?