# How to get lower case calligraphic font in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I want to use calligraphic style for my lower case letters in math mode in latex.

Searching throughout the internet, I have found two hinting solutions

1. Using [**boondox/dutchcal/mathalfa**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231322/how-to-get-the-lowercase-calligraphic-symbols), or
2. Using [**frcursive**](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1404).

However, I am getting errors on using each of the above solutions on MiKTeX 2.9 on windows.

What I am using for **option 1.** is the following:

```
\usepackage{mathalfa}
...
\mathbcal{c}
```

But it gives the error

```
Package mathalfa Error: There is no bold variant of the calligraphic 
font. ... = \left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\mathbcal{c}
```

Using **option 2.** as follows:

```
\usepackage{frcursive}
\newenvironment{frcseries}{\fontfamily{frc}\selectfont}{}
\newcommand{\textfrc}[1]{{\frcseries#1}}
\newcommand{\mathfrc}[1]{\text{\textfrc{#1}}}
...
\mathfrc{c}
```

gives the error

```
Font OT1/frc/m/it/12=frcsl12 at 12.0pt not loadable:
Metric (TFM) file not found. ... \left(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\mathfrc{c}
```

But if I use **dutchcal** for option 1. as

```
\usepackage{dutchcal}
...
\mathbcal{c}
```

I am getting the lowercase fonts which is too slanted to use.

Is there any easy way to get calligraphic lowercase letters in math mode?

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=29074&p=98180#p98179)

Answer (score 4):

The `\mathbcal` command is defined by `mathalfa` to choose the bold version, if available, but you don't need to use it: just `\mathcal` is sufficient:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{Hom}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, this is hardly what you really need. For such a case you should use a text font, not a math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{Hom}$

$\operatorname{\text{\usefont{U}{BOONDOX-cal}{m}{n}Hom}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the difference in spacing.

Answer (score 3):

Okay! It seems like I myself have found a solution using the package **pzccal** as posted in the link - [What are the options to get \mathcal working for lower case letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699375/what-are-the-options-to-get-mathcal-working-for-lower-case-letters).

```
\usepackage{pzccal}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{<-> s * [1.10] pzcmi7t}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
...
\mathpzc{c}
```