# How to selectively substitute a letter with another symbol representing the same letter

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

*First of all, sorry for the vague title, feel free to edit if you have a better one.*

I have two mathematical entities represented by the same symbol, say the letter *a*, that should be used *only* in math-mode. As both entities are usually represented with *a*, I would like to keep the same letter for both of them, but making them appear a little different.

How would you achieve that?

1. Finding an alternative symbol (preferred way; I tried using `\mathcal` but it supports only capital letters---otherwise the result would be satisfactory)
2. Loading another font altogether and print one of them in the second font
3. Another option

Requirements:

1. Support for *both* math-mode and bold face
2. No superscripts, hats, tildes etc.

Here is what both symbols should be able to do:
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$a$ $\boldsymbol{a}$ $\hat{\boldsymbol{a}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [See this link for lower case calligraphic letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348901/28808)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\mathsf`. But are you sure this is a good idea? I think it could be very hard for the reader to distinguish the two.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\symbola{a}
\def\symbolb{\mathsf a}

\begin{document}
$\symbola\symbolb%
\boldsymbol{\symbola}\boldsymbol{\symbolb}%
\hat{\symbola}\hat{\symbolb}%
\hat{\boldsymbol\symbola}\hat{\boldsymbol\symbolb}$
\end{document}
```

[image]