# A calligraphic font with small (lowercase) letters

Tags: fonts, mathcal

Is there a widely available calligraphic font that (1) contains small (lowercase) letters and (2) has a recognizably calligraphic capital letter O?

*Background*. (1) In mathematics (algebraic geometry), [one distinguishes "global" and "sheaf" versions certain constructions (Ext, Hom, ...)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local-to-global_Ext_spectral_sequence#Local-to-global_Ext_spectral_sequence), the latter being written in calligraphic script (standard notation for sheaves). However, most books end up typesetting the sheaf as follows

[image: global Ext, sheaf Ext]

pulling the small letters from the italics of a completely different font.

(2) The calligraphic capital letter O plays a special role in algebraic geometry, too, and most authors insist on it being recognizably calligraphic (i.e. not just a closed round loop)

---

*Edit.* The following are achieved with extra kerning from @egreg's and @UlrikeFischer's answers (in chronological order)

---

@egreg's answer

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\sHom}{\mathcal{H\mkern-7mu o\mkern-2.5mu m\mkern-1.5mu}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sExt}{\mathcal{E\mkern-4.5mu x\mkern-2.5mu t\mkern-1mu}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sEnd}{\mathcal{E\mkern-4mu n\mkern-4.5mu d\mkern-1mu}}
```

[image: egreg's answer]

---

@UlrikeFischer's answer

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathc}{m}{it}%
{<->s*[1.03] mathc10}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{U}{mathc}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sHom}{\mathcal{H\mkern-3mu om}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sExt}{\mathcal{E\mkern-3mu xt}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sEnd}{\mathcal{E\mkern-3mu nd}}
```

[image: UlrikeFischer's answer]

Comment: There are lots and lots of options for math-calligraphic and math-script fonts out there. (The screenshot you posted appears to feature the Computer Modern version of math-calligraphic uppercase letters.) I suggest you take a look at the user guide of the [mathalfa](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc) package to obtain an overview of available fonts -- many of which, happily, do provide lowercase calligraphic letters too.

Comment: You can take a look my answer to [how-to-get-the-lowercase-calligraphic-symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231322/how-to-get-the-lowercase-calligraphic-symbols/231348#231348) for three calligraphic typefaces with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try the `mathc` font (part of `mathabx`). It is not perfect, e.g. I would probably add a bit negative space between the `E` and the `x` but it has a distinct O and lowercases:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathc}{m}{it}%
{<->s*[1.03] mathc10}{}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{mathc}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sHomA}{\mathscr{Hom}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sExtA}{\mathscr{Ext}}


\begin{document}


\begin{gather*}
\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\\
\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\\
\Hom(A,B) \leftrightarrow \sHomA(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}) \\
\Ext(A,B) \leftrightarrow \sExtA(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}) \\
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what the line `{<->s*[1.03] mathc10}{}` does? I can't exactly google it

Comment: @RexYuan Don't ping single people in comments like this.  Ask a proper new question.

Answer (score 9):

The STIX fonts have a full fledged script alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\textscr}[1]{%
  \text{\usefont{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}#1}%
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sHom}{\textscr{Hom}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sExt}{\textscr{Ext}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\Hom(A,B) \leftrightarrow \sHom(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}) \\
\Ext(A,B) \leftrightarrow \sExt(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}) \\
\mathscr{O}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can get them also with the BOONDOX package, but imho the spacing isn't suitable for "three-letter-variables"

Comment: Great suggestion by egref...I've seen many of your answers, those are very useful...thanks a lot...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The spacing isn't perfect and the font looks like it isn't meant for writing words, but with extra kerning I think it's a viable alternative (see the update to my question).

Comment: the stix fonts should also have a full calligraphic alphabet, which doesn't have the curlicues of the script.  the stix script is quite unsuited to be used for "words".

Comment: @barbarabeeton I fully agree

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you desire that Hom, Ext and End be upright, here is one variation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{concmath-otf}

Code taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63188/128462

\usepackage{luatex85}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]
{%
    \mbox
    {%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
    }%
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{Ext}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sHomA}{\slantbox[-0.2]{\(\symcal{H}\)\kern-0.9pt\textit{om}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sExtA}{\slantbox[-0.2]{\(\symcal{E}\)\kern-0.7pt\textit{xt}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sEndA}{\slantbox[-0.2]{\(\symcal{E}\)\kern-0.8pt\textit{n\hspace{-0.2pt}d}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{gather*}
        \mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\\
        \mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\\
        \Hom(A,B) \leftrightarrow \sHomA(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}) \\
        \Ext(A,B) \leftrightarrow \sExtA(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}) \\
        \sExtA(\symscr{F}, \symscr{G}) \qquad \sEndA(\symscr{X})\\
        \symbf{R}^q\sHomA_{\symscr{O}}(F,-) = \sExtA^q_{\symscr{O}}(F,-)\\
        \symbb{R}^q\sHomA_{\symscr{O}}(F,-) = \sExtA^q_{\symscr{O}}(F,-)
    \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: concrete math calligraphic]

Now, Concrete Math does not really have a lowercase calligraphic font, but I think the italic one matches well, except for a very slight stroke width difference. It also seems that calligraphic H is slightly below o and m, but I don't know how to fix that. Here's how it looks for Libertinus and STIX Two, which provide lowercase calligraphic letters.

[image: libertinus calligraphic]

[image: stix two calligraphic]