# A calligraphic font with lowercase letters, using mathscr style and not bolded

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, calligraphy

In order to write calligraphic math symbols, I usually use `\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}` since I like it better than the vanilla `mathcal`.

However, now I am in need of writing full words, with upper and lower case letters, using such calligraphic style. Is there a way to do so that:

1. uses the `mathscr` style?
2. gives non-bolded letters?

For reference, a solution to a similar problem, but using vanilla `mathcal` and that produces bold letters has been giving in in the question: [A calligraphic font with small (lowercase) letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373513/a-calligraphic-font-with-small-lowercase-letters).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks you for the welcoming! :)

Comment: i already commented regarding an answer to the referenced question that the math script fonts are quite unsuited to setting words.  this is also mainly true of the designed-for-math calligraphic fonts, even if they have lowercase letters.  much better is a reasonably upright calligraphic font designed for text.  the only one i can think of off the top of my head is zapf chancery.  (hence a comment, not an answer; no time now to do research.)