"Fancy" math font with double brackets
how do I achieve this Val[[e]]p in LaTeX?

like the fancy V with the double brackets of e? I tried \textrm{Val}[\,[e_1]\,]\rho but it's not quite the same. Thank you!

Only partially, thanks for the info though!

Btw, if you want calligraphic a and l in Val, then you can use the mathabx package (original metafont, auto traced type 1). Add \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{stmaryrd} \DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathc}{} \DeclareFontShape{U}{mathc}{m}{it}% {<->s*[1.03] mathc10}{} \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{mathc}{m}{it} \DeclareMathOperator{\Val}{\mathcal{V}\mspace{-2.5mu}\mathscr{al}} to your preamble. From this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373539/128462

Welcome to TeX.SE!

I guess you want something like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Val}{\mathcal{V}\mspace{-2mu}\mathit{al}}

\begin{document}

$\Val\llbracket\mathtt{e}\rrbracket\rho$

\end{document}



That's it, thank you!

@Nerdenberg, please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
