Getting a symbol similar to number 1 but easily distinguishable from it

The symbol above is obtained with \mathds{1} from dsfont. I want a similar symbol but more readability (something similar and distinguishable from normal 1 but with no internal empty space inside the number)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}

$\mathds{1}$

\end{document}


Maybe \mathsf{1}?

And why is the question tagged [amsmath]?

@Mico. I usually use this for math environments

@campa. The topic is meant to ask for many possible options. Also, the question is tagged [amsmath] because this is the closest tag to the topic

How about a dingbat 1 in a circle. I have seen too many game theory papers using this. I am not too sure about your field though. Maybe you can give us some context

I've changed the tag from amsmath to symbols, and I've replaced the multi-row display-math environment with inline math mode. Feel free to revert.

A couple of suggestion:

1 in Helvetica bold
1 in Euler bold

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hone}{\text{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}1}}
\newcommand{\eone}{\text{\usefont{U}{zeur}{b}{n}1}}

\begin{document}

$1+\hone+\eone$

\end{document}



You can try the mathc part of the mathabx (https://ctan.org/pkg/mathabx) package.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathc}{m}{it}%
{<->s*[1.03] mathc10}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{U}{mathc}{m}{it} % Code copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373539

\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}
    \[1 + \textit{1}+ \mathds{1} + \mathsf{1} + \mathscr{1}\]
\end{document}


