# Is this a bug in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, amsmath, math-operators

I have tried to use this symbol in one of my equations:

```
\mathfrak{\mathcal{l}}
```

But, instead of showing that letter in mathcal and mathfrak styles, it shows updownarrow?!

I mean: `\mathfrak{\mathcal{l}}` gives exactly the same command of `\updownarrow`

Is it something wrong going here or there is a logical explanation?! I have checked it in WinEdt and also in the following online LaTeX equation editor:
https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Both give the same result!!

Thank you so much

Comment: `\mathfrak` and `\mathcal` are not ornaments to a font (in the manner of `\hat` or `\dot`).  Rather, they are separate fonts in themselves.  Thus, it makes no sense to try to combine them as you did.

Comment: also the is no lowercase mathcal. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231322/how-to-get-the-lowercase-calligraphic-symbols if you need a caligraphic.

Comment: What would a calligraphic fraktur letter be? (Accepting of course fraktur is a kind of calligraphy, but a very different kind to the loopy kind represented by `\mathcal`)

Comment: Your second question is completely separate from the first one, and in general it's better to make two posts in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for all these amazing comments .. Yeah, sure, the second part is separated and it can be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510483/why-winedt-gives-a-special-color-to-the-word-gui

Comment: You might want `\ell` for calligraphic small l.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Math alphabets don't combine, so with

```
\mathfrak{\mathcal{l}}
```

you get exactly the same as with

```
\mathcal{l}
```

which yields a “random” symbol, because `\mathcal` only has effect on *uppercase* letters.

Comment: Unless you load `unicode-math`, which does have ,  and .