# Why WinEdt gives a special color to the word GUI?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, winedt

When I write the word GUI, WinEdt automatically highlights it with a special color than the remaining texts!

What is the point here to give GUI a special color?

Thank you so much

Comment: Only with `GUI` or also with any other such word, like `PDF` for example? I don't use that editor but maybe it is because only 3 upper case letters.

Comment: Nope, only with GUI .. I have checked PDF and many other upper-case letters, nothing happen except for GUI!!

Comment: Have you considered posting this query to the winedt support site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be raised to WinEdt supporting forum

Comment: Based on your opinion, so all the topics raised here and related to WinEdt should be closed, and all the topics related to texmaker should also be closed since there are supporting forums!! The same thing for LyX, TexStudio, Overleaf, etc!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* a lot of words that behave the same or similar. These words can be found under `Options > Options Interface > Highlighting: ... > Keywords` which opens the `Keywords.ini` file. At the very end of the file you find the `KEYWORD_GROUP`s "Special" and "Special+" with the corresponding settings for highlighting.

If you don't need/want this highlighting adjust these groups to your need.