# Lowercase \mathscr and \mathcal letters

Tags: math-fonts

I'm sorry since I know this question has both been asked and answered before here, but I really am not good with computers and learning latex in itself has already been quite overwhelming. My question is: how do I write lowercase letters in `\mathscr` or `\mathcal` style?

I am using Overleaf and the packages used in other answers seem to not work there.

Please, if possible, use simple techniques, when I see a lot of code I simply don't understand what is going on :(

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us the code you have tried so far and can you show an image of what you want to get?

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about "the packages used in other answers" you've tried.

Comment: Yes, I tried each package from this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231322/how-to-get-the-lowercase-calligraphic-symbols

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true that the (vast?) majority of math-script and math-calligraphic font shapes provide only uppercase letters. For some math font packages that provide these font shapes for lowercase letters as well, please see the pages 8 thru 10 in the user guide of the [mathalpha](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) package.

Do also note that the terminology of what's a "calligraphic" or a "script" font shape isn't fully standardized. One working definition is that "script" letters are more heavily sloped than "calligraphic" letters are; however, do be aware that this is just one, and certainly not universally accepted, possible definition.

After perusing the user guide of the `mathalpha` package in the manner suggested above, I came up with the following choice: `esstix` for `\mathcal` and `\boondox` for `\mathscr`. Again, let me emphasize that this is just one particular possible choice. Others may come up with other choices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=boondox,  % heavily sloped
            cal=esstix]   % slightly sloped
           {mathalpha}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{abcABC} \quad \mathcal{abcABC}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would characterize script as more "curly", not necessarily more heavily sloped.  Calligraphic has a more "reserved" appearance, without a lot of flourishes and curlicues.

Comment: This definitely did work, thank you so much!!

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for this additional pointer. I guess I was associating, in my mind, more heavily sloped letters with "curlier" letters, and vice versa. For sure, this association is not all that precise in practice.

Answer (score 1):

All OpenType Math fonts have upper and lower case script/calligraphic letters (some have them in both styles)  in `unicode-math` this may be accessed with `\symscr` (or `\mathscr` alias)

so with lualatex or xelatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{abcABC}$

\end{document}
```

or

[image]

If I add

```
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
```