# How to define lowercase \mathscr letters?

Tags: symbols

I am currently trying to write down my mathematical model in Latex. I have been using [Latexeditor Lagrida](https://latexeditor.lagrida.com/) for this. There I can create this output with the command \mathscr{m}.

[image]

Now I have tried to implement the whole thing in Latex in TexStudio, but nothing is displayed there. I have obviously loaded the mathrsfs package.

How can I still define and use this lowercase letter?

Comment: You probably wish to have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668246).

Comment: the rsfs font does not  have lowercase, you need to choose a different font

Comment: that online editor seems to use `unicode-math` conventions so if I use `\symscr{abcABC}` I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrzLB.png)