# Macro changing a string depending on letter case

Tags: macros, conditionals, loops, strings, textcase

I would like to define a new mathmode command such that:

- the input is a string s;
- the output is the same string where the font of each caracter has been changed depending on whether the character is in lower case or upper case.

In pseudo-code, that would look like:

```
\newcommand{\cat}{
    forEach (character char in #1) {
        if (isLowerCase(char)) -> print \mathit{char}
        else -> print \mathcal{char}
    }
}
```

It seems I can use `ifthenelse` from the package `ifthen` for the if/else. I couldn't find how to:

- extract characters from string;
- loop for each of these characters;
- check whether a character is in lower case or not.

By the way, if anyone knows about a readable but nonetheless exhaustive reference on defining commands, I would appreciate (I could only find either too basic or "way over my head" references).

Thanks for your help!

PS: if anyone needs some context, I'm working in category theory, where the typical font for categories is \mathcal. Since lower case in mathcal is not defined, I need to find a way around it.

---

EDIT: I describe here my understanding of Ulrike Fischer's solution, as it might be useful to others.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\cat{m}
 {
   \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl {#1}
   \regex_replace_all:nnN {[a-z]}{\c{mathit}\cB\{\0\cE\}}\l_tmpa_tl
   \regex_replace_all:nnN {[A-Z]}{\c{mathcal}\cB\{\0\cE\}}\l_tmpa_tl
   \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

- `ExplSyntaxOn...ExplSyntaxOff`: change code régime where spaces are ignored and ":" and "_" are treated as letters. Necessary to access functions and variables. See interface3.pdf, p.7.
- `\NewDocumentCommand \cat {m} {...}`: create a new document-level function. You shall first describe the name (`\cat`), the set of parameters (`{m}`, one parameter which is refered as `#1` in the function code) and the function code itself (`{...}`). See xparse.pdf, p.7.
- `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}`: `\tl_set:Nn` set the value of some variable (or "token list", hence `tl`). `N` and `n` define the usual type of parameters for this function, `N` standing for a single token and `n` for a list of tokens between brackets. `\l_tmpa_tl` is a standard name of local temporary assigned token list.
- the first argument of `\regex_replace_all:nnN` is a list of tokens to be replaced, e.g. `{[a-z]}`. The second is what to do with these tokens, e.g. `{\c{mathit}\cB\{\0\cE\}}`. `\c{mathit}` is the equivalent of `\mathit` (for some reason, you can't just write `\mathit`). `\0` stands for everything that as been selected through the first argument. For some reason, it should be surrounded by `\cB\{...\cE\}`. Finally, the third argument is the token list on which the function is applied.
- the last `\l_tpma_tl` simply display the resulting token.

Comment: Try perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479/lowercase-mathcal

Comment: There is probably a way to get the same functionality with `range` from https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Thanks, but unfortunately I don't find any of these alternatives satisfying. On the other hand I have seen an article (https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.04133) using what I want to implement (i.e. mathcal for upper case and mathit for lower case), and it looked quite fine

Comment: which engine are you using? And if you are using lualatex/xelatex do you use unicode-math?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure : I compile with pdfLatex, does it answer your question ?

Comment: "string"  is not TeX-terminology. Please tell exactly what tokens can make up what you call a "string". E.g., what about curly braces and expandable tokens?

Comment: @UlrichDiez I meant a-Z characters. Note that Ulrike Fischer answered my question. Any help on understanding the source code (or simply good refs to do so) would still be welcome though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ulrike’s answer is fine, but we can improve it by removing unwanted kerns.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\AtBeginDocument{$\mathcal{\global\chardef\calfam=\fam}$}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__trynopsis_cat_neg:n
 {
  \mathchoice
   { \__trynopsis_cat_neg_aux:Nn \textfont { #1 } }
   { \__trynopsis_cat_neg_aux:Nn \textfont { #1 } }
   { \__trynopsis_cat_neg_aux:Nn \scriptfont { #1 } }
   { \__trynopsis_cat_neg_aux:Nn \scriptscriptfont { #1 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__trynopsis_cat_neg_aux:Nn
 {
  \kern -\fontcharic#1\calfam`#2
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\cat}{m}
 {
  \trynopsis_cat:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__trynopsis_cat_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \trynopsis_cat:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__trynopsis_cat_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([A-Z]) ([a-z]) } % search uppercase letter followed by a lowercase letter
   { \1 \c{__trynopsis_cat_neg:n} \1 \2 } % add a negative space in between
   \l__trynopsis_cat_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { [A-Z]+ } % search any run of uppercase letters
   { \c{mathcal}\cB\{\0\cE\} } % enclose it in \mathcal
   \l__trynopsis_cat_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { [a-z]+ } % search any run of lowercase letters
   { \c{mathit}\cB\{\0\cE\} } % enclose it in \mathit
   \l__trynopsis_cat_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \c{__trynopsis_cat_neg:n} \c{mathcal} }
   { \c{__trynopsis_cat_neg:n} }
   \l__trynopsis_cat_tl
  % deliver the new token list
  \tl_use:N \l__trynopsis_cat_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__trynopsis_cat_neg:
 {
  \mspace{-2mu}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\cat{Set}\quad\cat{Grp}\quad\cat{Abc\_def}$

$\scriptstyle\cat{Set}\quad\cat{Grp}\quad\cat{Abc\_def}$

\end{document}
```

The fourth replacement transforms the unwanted `\__trynopsis_cat_neg:n \mathcal {<letter>}` into `\__trynopsis_cat_neg:n {<letter>}`.

The purpose of `\__trynopsis_cat_neg:n` is to remove the excess space when an uppercase (calligraphic) letter is followed by a lowercase (italic) one.

[image]

Comment: thanks! that indeed looks better, especially with the Vec category.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you only have a-Z in the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mycal{m}
 {
   \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl {#1}
   \regex_replace_all:nnN {[a-z]}{\c{mathit}\cB\{\0\cE\}}\l_tmpa_tl
   \regex_replace_all:nnN {[A-Z]}{\c{mathcal}\cB\{\0\cE\}}\l_tmpa_tl
   \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\mycal{abcABC}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the effect I needed. Any suggestion on where I could look to understand the source code ?

Comment: the regex code is described in interface3.pdf. You get it with texdoc interface3.