# Mathpazo has wrong index of $\mathcal{D_\rho}$

Tags: math-fonts, mathpazo

I try to use `mathpazo` in my LaTeX notes, that is `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`, but something wrong happens with `$\mathcal{D_\rho}$`. I expect it to be

[image]

which works when I do not load the `mathpazo` package, while with `mathpazo` the result is

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479/15036

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of `\mathcal` should be an *uppercase Latin*-alphabet letter. With some math fonts -- though not with `mathpazo` -- the arguments of `\mathcal` can also be lowercase Latin-alphabet letters. For sure, though, I know of no math font package that enables `\mathcal` to operate meaningfully on *greek*-alphabet letters.

In short, do change `\mathcal{D_\rho}` to `\mathcal{D}_{\rho}`.

Aside: `\mathcal{\rho}` is a user error. Just because LaTeX doesn't crash and burn when it encounters `\mathcal{\rho}` is not proof that it's an instruction that has a chance of producing something meaningful. The fact that `\mathcal{\rho}` outputs `\rho` if the `mathpazo` package is not loaded simply means that the default math font (Computer Modern Math) has been trained to simply ignore the `\mathcal` wrapper if its argument is `\rho`, and maybe other Greek-alphabet characters too. It is *not* a sign that it's meaningful to run `\mathcal{\rho}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

% 'mathpazo' is close to being obsolete. Do consider using:
%\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext} 
%\usepackage{newpxmath}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{D_\rho}$ vs.\ $\mathcal{D}_{\rho}$
\end{document}
```